# Sort columns in MySQL Workbench

Tags: mysql-workbench

I'm wondering if there is a way to sort the columns of a table in a MySQL Workbench 6.3 diagram as follows:

- Primary key column(s) first
- Other columns alphabetically

Of course, I can manually drag-and-drop the columns by hand, but that's a tedious process, to say the least.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, this is not possible, as it also means to "physically" change the order of the columns in a database (once you synchronize your changes with the server).

Comment: I'm only roughly familiar with ordinal positions of SQL columns. I think most of the time use of the ordinal position is discouraged, because the queries tend to be unclear and difficult to maintain. Is the order of columns in fact important; if so, in what way?

Comment: Well, probably not that important, but the columns are stored and returned in the order they were when the table was created (or altered). So, when you update a table without specifiying the columns you could get into trouble.

Comment: As a practical matter, what's the best practice regarding columns? When viewing a diagram of a SQL table, I find it difficult to locate a particular column when the columns are not in alphabetical order. At work we've even had instances where Developer A added a column to a table with > 100 columns (I wouldn't have made a table with > 100 columns, but it wasn't my decision to make) without realizing that the column already existed (likely because looking through > 100 columns is one-by-one is tedious).

Comment: Well, there is no best practices, other than not creating tables with such many columns. However, as soon as you add a column with a name that is already used you will get an error from the server. So that should not really be a problem. What would be nice is a filter for column names in the table editor.

Answer (score 0):

Late but might be useful. You can do that in Adminer. Install adminer from adminer.org. See in the attached pic.

[image]